# Java String Insertion error

Tags: java, string, random

Whenever I run this method-

```
stringBot = bot.getText();
        stringTop = top.getText();
        intBot = stringBot.length();
        intTop = stringTop.length();
        String stringMove = "";
        r=0+Math.random()*intTop;
        if (intBot > intTop &&intBot>1 ){
              lastBot = stringBot.charAt(intBot-1);




 //stringMove =stringTop.substring(0,(int) r) + lastBot + stringTop.substring(intTop+1);



              top.setText(stringTop);
              stringBot=stringBot.substring(0,intBot-1);

              bot.setText(stringBot);
        }
        else if (intTop >= intBot &&intTop>1 ){
              lastTop = stringTop.charAt(intTop-1);
              stringMove = stringMove+lastTop;
              top.setText(stringBot+stringMove);
              stringTop=stringTop.substring(0,intTop-1);

              top.setText(stringTop);
        }
```

I get an error at the commented section, Please help me. The error isn't exactly syntactical because when i compile it does not recognize the error until i actually run the method when i click the left button. Then it gives me a terminal window

Comment: Where does the error happen exactly (line number), and what does it say?

Comment: What is the declared type of `r`?

Comment: What error do you get exactly?

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
 at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1875)
 at Driver.leftAction(Driver.java:40)
 at ThreeButtons$ThreeButtonFrame.actionPerformed(ThreeButtons.java:65)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)

Comment: full error stack trace?

Comment: r is declared as a double

Comment: For an example of what this is supposed to do go here-http://www.cs.uwlax.edu/~riley/CS120S13/Assignments/StrungOutApplet/Driver.html       Click mid, then click left-this method is for the left button

Comment: For whatever reason, your variable `r` is negative. A String cannot have a character in a negative index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `stringTop.substring(intTop+1)` where `intTop = stringTop.length();`.
So you should have exception because `intTop+1` > length of `stringTop`.

Comment: umm i did intTop--; in the if instruction right above the substring, is this legal    It resolve my problem but now I have another problem where it doesnt transfer the characters from bot to top,

Comment: Yes, you can do it if you need, why not.